# Possible conflicts with fixltx2e?

Tags: packages, best-practices, incompatibility

I only recently came across the [fixltx2e package](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/fixltx2e.html). Given that it patches aspects of LaTeX, my spidey-sense begins to tingle out of a concern for possible package conflicts.

Are there known conflicts? Is it better to load fixltx2e early, or, like [hyperref](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/help/Catalogue/entries/hyperref.html), as late as possible? (Yes, I am worrying about a problem I don't as yet have. But, the concern won't be fresh in my mind six months from now if some conflict produces a hard to figure out bug.)

I'd originally thought that there was little documentation, as none is linked on the CTAN Catalogue page that I used as the package link. In light of the answer, I thought to run `texdoc fixltx2e1` in the terminal. It turns out there is an extensive amount of documentation available, just not where I am used to looking for a new package.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Load `fixltx2e` before `footmisc`.

`memoir` and `subfig` have special compatibility code to deal with `fixltx2e`, so it seems to be possible to have conflicts, but I have not had to deal with any.

Answer (score 6):

The documentation for `fixltx2e` says only to load it in the preamble. It sounds like it doesn't matter where in the preamble you load it. I tend to do it right after the `\documentclass`.

Answer (score 5):

Load the `amsthm` package before `fixltx2e`.

Latex gives an error if it's the other way around: `latex> ! You can't use macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode. latex> <argument> \hskip \labelsep \itshape ## latex> 1\@addpunct {.} latex> l.441 #1\@addpunct{.}] latex> \ignorespaces latex> ! Too many }'s. latex> l.442 } latex> {% latex> ! Undefined control sequence. latex> \qed ...}\nobreak \hfill \quad \hbox {\qedsymbol latex> }\fi`

Comment: Could you give an explanation or a reference to why this is necessary, please?

Comment: @diabonas: Latex gives an error if it's the other way around:
`latex> ! You can't use macro parameter character #' in restricted horizontal mode.
latex> <argument> \hskip \labelsep \itshape ##
latex>                                        1\@addpunct {.}
latex> l.441     #1\@addpunct{.}]
latex>                           \ignorespaces
latex> ! Too many }'s.
latex> l.442 }
latex>        {%
latex> ! Undefined control sequence.
latex> \qed  ...}\nobreak \hfill \quad \hbox {\qedsymbol 
latex>                                                   }\fi`

Comment: Oh ok, this is indeed a very convincing argument to respect the correct order ;-) Could you edit your answer to include this error message, please?

Comment: ? That's strange. I tried to add `fixltx2e` to a rather lengthy document, and eventually discovered that including `amsmath`, `ulem` and `fixltx2e` in this order causes the compilation to hang indefinitely on `\[ … \]` parts. Even on a dumb `\[a\]`. Loading `fixltx2e` first corrects this o( o_o )o This is all too weird for me ; I think I'll do without this stuff.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of any conflicts, but that's not saying much... I don't think it really matters when in the preamble you load it.