# Packages that need to be included in a specific order

Tags: packages, big-list, incompatibility

This isn't a real question, so I'm marking it community wiki.

When I was new to LaTeX, I thought that the `\usepackage` command worked much like the `#include` command of the C language: just put whatever you need in the preamble, in whatever order you like.

But then bugs began to bite me and I realised, with growing horror, that commutative packages seem to be the exception rather than the rule.

[They](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before) [appear](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2859/should-the-fontenc-package-be-loaded-before-or-after-font-packages) so [often](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/possible-conflicts-with-fixltx2e) that I think it would be useful to have a list here of problematic interactions between pairs of packages, and their correct order.

Also, a question for amusement:

I want to know if there exists three packages `A`, `B` and `C`, such that `A` has to be included before `B` and `B` needs to be included before `C`, but `C` needs to be included before `A`.

Comment: Is that last sentence a question if three such packages exist?

Comment: Hmm. Better reword it.

Comment: Note that C isn't immune to non-commutative inclusions: #include just literally pastes in the relevant source code file at that point before compilation. C header file writers tend to be better at not messing with each other, and C more tolerant for changing definitions.

Comment: The same way that LaTeX's problems are caused by the packages, not by the command. Actually, once while C programming I managed to make such a tangle of headers that included each other that the compiler gave up and refused to resolve it.

Comment: `\usepackage` does work like the `#include` directive, and if you could overwrite existing definitions in C, you'd run into the same issues that LaTeX has.

Comment: At least in theory, you could have just two packages that don't "play nice": If both package `foo` and package `bar` both redefine two commands, `\jedi` and `\sith`, and you want `foo`'s `\jedi` but `bar`'s `\sith`, then no order of package loading will get you both...

Comment: Yes. SIunits and amssymb fit your description exactly; they both want the \square command (although you have ways to solve the conflict). But that's not what I asked.

Comment: As much as I like using math terminology for non-math situations, this question seemed to be a bit hard to find for non-math people. I changed the title to something more directly descriptive.

Comment: To be honest, I would be glad if a new feature of CTAN would emerge, an underlying graph whose edges connect each two conflicting packages with a short description with details. Then, automatic discovery of currently perilous package orders could be automatically detected by lacheck, latex or other programs. The main idea is to let the package authors register after which packages their package is incompatible. Currently, this knowledge is hidden in its completeness in many, many documentation PDF files for the packages.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Freek Dijkstra has put together a nice wiki of [Latex package conflicts](http://www.macfreek.nl/mindmaster/LaTeX_package_conflicts).  Hyperref is the one he singles out for criticism: it has the nasty property that sometimes it conflicts when it is put earlier, sometimes when it is put later than other widely used packages, encouraging cargo-cult document headers.

He's had less trouble with inputenc conflicts that others, judging from complaints that I've seen, mostly, I guess, because he uses Xetex.

Comment: Of course you have less trouble with `inputenc` in XeLaTeX, simply because you never load `inputenc`.

Comment: Regarding `hyperref`: it's not the hyperref package that is to be criticized, but rather the LaTeX2e kernel, which seems to combine every possible software development antipattern in a single package.

Comment: @Philipp - You might load inputenc if you run xelatex on a document written by someone else who is using Pdftex.

Answer (score 3):

The big list is available at https://github.com/mhelvens/latex-pkgloader/blob/master/pkgloader-recommended.sty with explanations.

Example:

```latex
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
%
%  A list of recommended rules derived from
%  <http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossaries-user.pdf>,
%  <http://mirrors.dotsrc.org/ctan/macros/latex/contrib/glossaries/glossariesbegin.pdf>:
%
%    \begin{macrocode}
\Load {hyperref} before  {glossaries}
                 if loaded
                 because {otherwise terms won't be
                          clickable hyperlinks}
\Load {glossaries} after {babel,polyglossia,inputenc,
                          fontenc,doc}
                 if loaded
                 because {the glossaries documentation
                          explicitly says to do so}
%    \end{macrocode}
%
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
```

Since this is an open source project, pull requests updating the knowledgebase are very welcome!

Answer (score 2):

```
mathtools
```

needs to go before

```
mathabx
```

Comment: but `mathabx` changes essentially every single symbol, so be very sure you really want to do that before using it.  there are ways to load just a few symbols from those fonts; see [Importing a Single Symbol From a Different Font](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/14386/579).

Comment: Huh, okay I didn't know that. I posted a question about it but it got closed saying it was a duplicate of this question. Result: I still don't know anything.

Comment: i posted a rather substantial comment on the closed question.  i think you might find that helpful.  (of course, i'm biased.  on the other hand, i have >30 years of experience with tex, so that should count for something.)  if what you're working on is a thesis, take a look at nicola talbot's (excellent!) book, [Using LaTeX to Write a PhD Thesis](http://www.dickimaw-books.com/latex/thesis/thesis-screen.pdf).

Comment: Okay, thx a lot. Too bad it couldn't have been an answer though, sometimes the comments slip through the cracks.

Answer (score 0):

`titlesec` has to be loaded before `beamerarticle`
as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/84273/using-titlesec-in-beamerarticle-with-a-modified-section-command)