# BibTeX in LaTeX document

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

For referencing in my LaTeX documents, I use the `thebibliography` command. However most of the times I find the information of my citations in BibTeX format. Manually editing BibTeX file to convert them to `\bibitem` is exhausting. I want to know if there is any method for importing a bibTeX file or a command which could understand the text structure of a BibTeX file in LaTeX?

Comment: This question is answered in nearly every introduction. One example is here: http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Bibliography_Management -- You should use `biblatex` to manage your bibliography on LaTeX site.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel Thank you. But here the only method is to import your .bib file. Is there anyway to do it in the same file without importing anything. To make the tex file process the material of a .bib file by copying it into TeX file.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid `biblatex` or BibTex? After compiling with `bibtex` you have file with the extension `bbl`. This file contains the environment `thebibliography`.

Comment: The only reason is I want to keep everything in the same file.
Plus, right now half of my citations are as bibitems, not bibTeX files.

Comment: In my opinion it isn't a good way to provide only one single file. Structuring a document has a lot of benefits: [Techniques and packages to keep up with good practices](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19264/techniques-and-packages-to-keep-up-with-good-practices/20191#20191)  -- Nevertheless you can use the package `filecontents`. So you can have the contents of your bib-file in your single file and you can edit the entries.

Comment: @MarcoDaniel, that is true. But now I have to manually change all of my old bibitems to bibTeX format. Right? Cause bibTeX does not compile "bibitem"s.

Comment: That's correct. But providing a database of bib-entries will help you later. And you can manipulate string global.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you really want to follow this way, you can create a new document, let's say `test.tex` with the following contents:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{biblio}
\end{document}
```

where `biblio` is the name of your `.bib` file.

Then run

`pdflatex test`

`bibtex test`

`pdflatex test`

`pdflatex test`

At this point, open the file `test.bbl` and copy its contents to your original `.tex` file