# Convert .bib to bibitems

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, citing

The journal I am submitting to prefers a list of `bibitem`s over a `.bib` file. In trying to make this conversion, I used the suggestions from [this SE question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124874/converting-to-bibitem-in-latex) and [this blog post](http://texblog.org/2011/12/12/bib2tex-converting-bibtex-to-bibitems/).

Running `pdflatex`, `bibtex` on the MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}
\begin{document}
Theory of superconductivity~\cite{bardeen1957}.
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

with `bibliography.bib`:

```
@article{bardeen1957,
    title       = {Theory of superconductivity},
    author      = {Bardeen, John and Cooper, Leon N and Schrieffer, J Robert},
    journal     = {Physical Review},
    volume      = {108},
    number      = {5},
    pages       = {1175},
    year        = {1957},
    publisher   = {APS}
}
```

should result in a `.bbl` file with the bibitems in the form

```
\bibitem{bardeen1957}
Bardeen, J.
\newblock Theory of superconductivity.
\newblock {\em Physical Review}{\bf 108}
\newblock 1175 (1975)
```

Instead, I get in the file `mwe.bbl`:

```
\entry{bardeen1957}{article}{}
  \name{author}{3}{}{%
    {{}%
     {Bardeen}{B.}%
     {John}{J.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
    {{}%
     {Cooper}{C.}%
     {Leon~N}{L.~N.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
    {{}%
     {Schrieffer}{S.}%
     {J~Robert}{J.~R.}%
     {}{}%
     {}{}}%
  }
  \list{publisher}{1}{%
    {APS}%
  }
  \strng{namehash}{BJ+1}
  \strng{fullhash}{BJCLNSJR1}
  \field{number}{5}
  \field{pages}{1175}
  \field{title}{Theory of superconductivity}
  \field{volume}{108}
  \field{journaltitle}{Physical Review}
  \field{year}{1957}
\endentry
```

What am I doing wrong, and how do I get the preferred `\bibitem{}` form of entries?

Comment: try to replace `\printbibliography` with `\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}` and don't use `\usepackage[backend=bibtex,style=nature]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`

Comment: `\documentclass{article}
    \bibliography{bibliography}
    \bibliographystyle{plain}
    \begin{document}
    Theory of superconductivity~\cite{bardeen1957}.
    \end{document}` 

gives `Missing 'biblatex' package. {}`, independent of whether I put the commands in the preamble or body. Including the `biblatex` line gives the error `Package biblatex Error: '\bibliographystyle' invalid. \bibliographystyle{plain}` when including the style line, and the old result from the question without it.

Comment: after you remove the `\usepackage[...]{biblatex}` you need to delete your `.aux` file(s), because they still contain the now-irrelevant links.

Comment: Done, still gives the old `\entry{bardeen1957}{article}{}` etc

Comment: no you only get `\entry...` using biblatex if you have removed that (and re-run pdflatex and bibtex) then they will be gone

Comment: Ah yes, it does. Not sure what I did wrong first, but this code works:
`\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\cite{bardeen1957}.
\bibliography{bibliography}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}`

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is solved by comments.

Comment: "Thanks" for closing this instead of just allowing a commenter to answer. Had to hunt down here to find a solution – wicked! How is a question off-topic if it's being solved? That makes all questions on this site off-topic! You guys amaze me sometimes.