# Quotes and commas in \bibitem

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, punctuation, quotation, bibitem

I have followed
[Converting to bibitem in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/124874/converting-to-bibitem-in-latex)
to convert into the \bibitem format.

However, the results are not as good as when I would have used the regular `references.bib` file.

For example, one of my entries in the `references.bib` file is :

```
@inproceedings{dansereau2013decoding,
  title={Decoding, calibration and rectification for lenselet-based plenoptic cameras},
  author={Dansereau, Donald G and Pizarro, Oscar and Williams, Stefan B},
  booktitle={Proceedings of the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition},
  pages={1027--1034},
  year={2013}
}
```

This generates in my pdf as :
[image]

Now after compiling the latex file and generating the pdf, I copy the required `\bibitem` lines from the `output.bbl` log file which is obtained :

```
\bibitem{dansereau2013decoding}
D.~G. Dansereau, O.~Pizarro, and S.~B. Williams, ``Decoding, calibration and
  rectification for lenselet-based plenoptic cameras,'' in {\em Proceedings of
  the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition},
  pp.~1027--1034, 2013.
```

But now my pdf file generates as the following with this bibitem format :
[image]

The quotes and commas have drastically changed and do not look as presentable as the first result.
How do I generate the `\bibitem` contents from the `.bbl` files to get the same style of commas and quotes like I would have using a simple `references.bib` file

EDIT:

I had inserted my orginal `referneces.bib` file using :

```
\bibliographystyle{ieeetr}
\footnotesize
\bibliography{references.bib}
```

The new article with the bibitem format has :

```
\reftitle{References}
\begin{thebibliography}{999}
\bibitem{dansereau2013decoding}
D.~G. Dansereau, O.~Pizarro, and S.~B. Williams, ``Decoding, calibration and
  rectification for lenselet-based plenoptic cameras,'' in {\em Proceedings of
  the IEEE conference on computer vision and pattern recognition},
  pp.~1027--1034, 2013.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Comment: We need more information here. Conversion from `.bib` to `.bbl` is not automatic. It is controlled by a bibtex style which also governs the formatting you want to change. But you never mentions which style you are currently using

Comment: You seem to be using Palatino as the text font and that’s precisely the shape the quotes have in the font.

Comment: @daleif I have provided information on the bibtex styles. Hope that gives a better insight

Comment: @egreg the new article does not have a mention of the Palatino font anywhere

Comment: @JoshithaR There are a few packages that provide it: mathpazo or newpxtext