# Converting bibtex to bibitem: occurance of \newblock

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, conversion

I get a `\newblock` when I convert `bibtex` to `bibitem` using the method in [BibTeX in LaTeX document](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/109876/bibtex-in-latex-document/109888#109888)

my code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\bibliography{biblio}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

my `biblio.bib` file:

```
% survey

@article{erol2007vision,
  title={Vision-based hand pose estimation: A review},
  author={Erol, Ali and Bebis, George and Nicolescu, Mircea and         Boyle, Richard D and Twombly, Xander},
  journal={Computer Vision and Image Understanding},
  volume={108},
  number={1},
  pages={52--73},
  year={2007},
  publisher={Elsevier}
}
```

the generated `test.bbl` file:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{erol2007vision}
Ali Erol, George Bebis, Mircea Nicolescu, Richard~D Boyle, and     Xander Twombly.
\newblock Vision-based hand pose estimation: A review.
\newblock {\em Computer Vision and Image Understanding}, 108(1):52-    -73, 2007.

\end{thebibliography}
```

the `test.pdf` generated looks like:

> References
>
> [1] Ali Erol, George Bebis, Mircea Nicolescu, Richard D Boyle, and
>   Xander Twombly. Vision-based hand pose estimation: A review. Computer
>   Vision and Image Understanding, 108(1):52–73, 2007.

Is the `test.bbl` correct? What is the newblock thing? Does it comply with ieee robotics requirements? http://ras.papercept.net/conferences/support/tex.php

Comment: Yes, you are fine, don't worry. IEEE has its own bst file though maybe you should use `IEEEtran.bst` instead of `plain.bst`.

Comment: IEEE also has its own documentclass.

Comment: You would think that a robotics and automation journal likes to be at the edge of technology, but ... they should really really really update their website concerning TeX and friends.

Comment: @Joahnnes: Thanks for your replies. The IEEEtran.bst is in the folder from which I am compiling the tex file. Do I have to include it in the code somehow? I havent used any other plain.bst

Comment: In the code at the very top, you have `\bibliographystyle{plain}`. Substitute.

Comment: thanx a lot. it worked.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is about a nonissue.