# Modern Idiomatic LaTeX

Tags: best-practices

Following up on [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/82414/233148) by @egreg and [this question specifically on LaTeX3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/633551/latest-user-level-manuals-for-latex-3-follow-up-to-ivo-welch?rq=1), where can I find some reasonable documentation or discussion on writing modern idiomatic LaTeX for composing documents? Ideally something with LaTeX3 in mind (i.e., `xparse`, `l3keys2e`, &c., not `interface3.pdf`), but even just a within-the-last-decade of how LaTeX2e documents should be written.

Note: I won't normally read technical information more than a decade old unless someone specifically says "LaTeX2e was frozen in 1994, so literally anything since then is accurate up until 2018"; I would *love* if there were some documentation on modern document-level idiomatic LaTeX!

Documentation I have already read:

- [xparse.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/xparse.pdf)
- [l3keys2e.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3packages/l3keys2e.pdf)
- [classes.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex-dev/base/classes.pdf)
- [lthooks-doc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex-dev/base/lthooks-doc.pdf)
- [ltfilehooks-doc.pdf](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex-dev/base/ltfilehook-doc.pdf)
- [usrguide3.pdf](https://www.latex-project.org/help/documentation/usrguide3.pdf)
- ...

Other related questions that don't answer my question:

- [How to read LaTeX2e sources](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3043/are-there-guidelines-on-how-to-read-commented-sources-of-latex-packages)
- [coding style guidelines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/40775/are-there-any-coding-style-guidelines-for-latex?rq=1)
- [latex styleguid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12171/styleguide-for-latex-similar-to-the-google-styleguides)
- [coding conventions](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95687/what-are-coding-conventions-in-latex?rq=1)
- [cleaning code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134972/cleaning-my-tex-code?rq=1)
- [keep up to date with best practices](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19264/techniques-and-packages-to-keep-up-with-good-practices?noredirect=1&lq=1)
- [writing clean latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/378395/good-practice-rules-for-writing-clean-latex?rq=1)

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @Community bot, I would like a link or reference or huge answer explaining what would be considered good modern idiomatic LaTeX. I included some examples of what should be answered by such a reference. Thanks for the over broad pattern-matching!

Comment: `lua` code is so much nicer and easier to read than `latex3 code`. I have no idea why one would choose to write internal latex code in `latex3` when there is `lua` available in lualatex. Is there something that latex3 gives, that can't be done with lua? (assuming one wants to only use lualatex compiler)

Comment: @Nasser, I see a lot of comments on this site about Lua v. LaTeX3, but that's just silly talk. Lua is a programming language (available via LuaTeX, I know). I'm not asking about how to write a linked list data structure or csv parser or how to interact with a SQL server. I'm talking about writing documents for PDF. Snark aside, I legit don't understand why they're being compared; it's apples-to-oranges.

Comment: the specific list is rather hard to answer given the title and opening paragraph. You _could_ ask about where to find information on current latex and L3 programming layer idioms. But your actual list of questions are all about classic latex and tex primitives, answers to the first bullet re `\bf` haven't changed since 1994 and the rest haven't really changed since the 1980s.

Comment: @Nasser yes lots, the overlap in functionality is rather small.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I'll try to re-word my question. Those examples aren't my question; just examples flowing from the first link.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle, I just removed the list of example questions. I think it was just a distraction that escaped my brain due to my thought process. Really, I just want a `lshort.pdf` that is correct and current for LaTeX in 2022 (i.e., uses `\NewDocumentCommand` rather than `\newcommand`), but more importantly doesn't suggest I use `\def` half the time (unless there is a concrete reason why that's better sometimes?).

Comment: @gaelicWizard `\newcommand` is not deprecated in favor of `\NewDocumentCommand`, I don't see why a "LaTeX in 2022" manual would encourage users to use the `xparse` syntax as much as possible