# Using listing with minted gets wrong listoflistings

Tags: table-of-contents, hyperref, listings, lists, minted

I wanted to make a `\begin{minted}` block to show on the ToC in Listings section with a link to its label. So I did (with links to my Github working repo)

```
\begin{listing}[!h]
    \begin{minted}[
        linenos,
        frame=single,
        numbersep=6pt,
        baselinestretch=1,
        fontfamily=courier,
        gobble=4,
        fontsize=\tiny,
    ]{text}
    code code code
    \end{minted}
    \caption{some caption}
    \label{code:mytextfile}
\end{listing}
```

[using minted listing](https://github.com/paulochf/tcc/blob/master/Chapters/Chapter3.tex#L121)

to label my code to get the right link, and

```
\renewcommand\listingscaption{Code}
\renewcommand\listoflistingscaption{List of Source codes}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99656/5125
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}%
    \listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}%
}
```

[template and preamble](https://github.com/paulochf/tcc/blob/master/tcc.tex#L156)

to show a List of Listings on the ToC (were not showing with a simple `\listoflistings`, so I put `addcontentsline`), with custom texts on it. This produces a problem that, at the "Source code List", clicking on the entry for the listing takes the document to the cover. I cannot go better than this: if I change something, or the "List of Source codes" entry takes to "List of Figures", or it disappears.

---

Edit: [duplicate](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19371/minteds-listing-environment-with-hyperref-and-caption-package-together), althought I could not fix my problem yet.

Comment: Sorry, but you can't expect we go through a complete book. Please try and make a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows the issue.

Comment: At least I pointed the parts where I used it. I didn't expected someone was going to search the problem for his own.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going against what I thought it was, the problem was the hyperref package. As [this other post here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/19371/minteds-listing-environment-with-hyperref-and-caption-package-together) hinted, the include's order was bogus, but also I had to add a `\phantomsection`.

So, my preamble was

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% color
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

% Blue links
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

% "Natbib" style for references
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

% \makeglossaries
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Using_defined_terms
\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}

% http://texblog.org/tag/addcontentsline/
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}

% \newminted{cpp}
% [chapter] to number by chapter
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}

% TODO anotations
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,portuguese]{todonotes}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{caption}       % \begin{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}      % required by {babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % \includegraphics
\usepackage{subcaption}    % \begin{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim}      % \begin{comment}
\usepackage{fullpage}      % thinner margins
\usepackage{indentfirst}   % indent 1st paragraphs
\usepackage{setspace}      % \setstretch
\usepackage{afterpage}     % \afterpage https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657

% turning 'fi' ligatures off
% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=953#p13896
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}
```

Changing the include's order, turned into

```
\usepackage[brazil]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% color
\usepackage[table,dvipsnames]{xcolor}

\usepackage{caption}       % \begin{caption}
\usepackage{csquotes}      % required by {babel}
\usepackage{graphicx}      % \includegraphics
\usepackage{subcaption}    % \begin{subfigure}
\usepackage{verbatim}      % \begin{comment}
\usepackage{fullpage}      % thinner margins
\usepackage{indentfirst}   % indent 1st paragraphs
\usepackage{setspace}      % \setstretch
\usepackage{afterpage}     % \afterpage https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88657

% \newminted{cpp}
% [chapter] to number by chapter
\usepackage[chapter]{minted}

% Blue links
\usepackage[unicode,colorlinks=true,linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}

% turning 'fi' ligatures off
% http://www.latex-community.org/forum/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=953#p13896
\usepackage{microtype}
\DisableLigatures{encoding = *, family = *}

% "Natbib" style for references
\usepackage[backend=biber,bibencoding=utf8,style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}

% \makeglossaries
% http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Glossary#Using_defined_terms
\usepackage[xindy,toc]{glossaries}

% http://texblog.org/tag/addcontentsline/
\usepackage[numbib]{tocbibind}

% TODO anotations
\usepackage[colorinlistoftodos,portuguese]{todonotes}
```

and the renew command for `\listoflistings` with the `\phantomsection`

```
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/99656/5125
\renewcommand{\listoflistings}{%
    \cleardoublepage
    \phantomsection
    \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{\listoflistingscaption}%
    \listof{listing}{\listoflistingscaption}%
}
```

Now, clicking the list of listings entry on table of contents guides to the right page of the listing.