# Which packages that apply fixes should one load by default?

Tags: packages

## The problem

Throughout the years I have come across several packages that fix issues in (La)TeX. It seems like it would be a good idea to load these by default. However, I could not find an authoritative list giving a qualified recommendation for which packages one should load. With this question, I would like you to fill that gap.

## What to answer

Please give a list that is as complete as possible. You could mention:

- Package name
- The problems it addresses
- In which context it should be used
- Possible caveats

## A first start

#### Core fixes

Just for a head start, here are a few packages that I know of:

- [`fixltx2e`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fixltx2e)

  - *Problems addressed:* Fixes some fundamental bugs in LaTeX that cannot be included in the core version because they could break backwards compatibility
  - *Use in:* Any LaTeX document
  - *[Caveats:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2835/possible-conflicts-with-fixltx2e)* Load `amsthm` before this package; load `footmisc` after this package
- [`mparhack`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mparhack)

  - *Problems addressed:* Fixes a problem where marginpars sometimes appear on the wrong side
  - *Use in:* Any LaTeX document (that uses marginpars)
  - *Caveats:* ???

#### Fixes to document classes

- [`scrhack`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/koma-script/)

  - *Problems addressed:* Fixes several conflicts with other packages
  - *Use in:* Any document written with KOMA script classes (scrartcl, *etc.*)
  - *Caveats:* ???

#### Math fixes

- [`mathtools`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathtools)

  - *Problems addressed:* Fixes several issues in `amsmath` and introduces new commands. Load instead of `amsmath`
  - *Use in:* Any document with mathematics
  - *Caveats:* ???
- [`lualatex-math`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/lualatex-math)

  - *Problems addressed:* Fixes some problems that can occur when typesetting mathematics with LuaLaTeX
  - *Use in:* Documents that contain mathematics and are compiled with LuaLaTeX
  - *Caveats:* ???

#### Fonts

- [`fix-cm`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/fix-cm)

  - *Problems addressed:* Fixes issues with the original computer modern fonts
  - *Use in:* Documents use the old computer modern fonts
  - *[Caveats:](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/98255/should-i-use-fix-cm)* Do not use in new files, use it only for compatibility. Use `lmodern` instead.

#### Potentially helpful / best practices

- [`nag`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nag)

  - *Problems addressed:* Gives warnings for bad practices
  - *Use in:* Any document
  - *Caveats:* Can annoy you if you use old commands

Comment: Regarding caveats, the order in which those packages are loaded may matter.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, in the deed, that is what I meant. Sorry for the mix up!

Comment: Personally, I don't like having packages in my preamble for reasons I don't understand. Each of my documents has a minimally required preamble with possibly no unused packages. So I never load `fixltx2e` because I don't know what it does, and its manual is quite cryptic. However it is implicitly loaded by many other packages I use, and they hopefully know why they load it.

Comment: @marczellm: I put `\RequirePackage{fixltx2e}` before `\documentclass{revtex}` in order to compile my doucment with `xelatex` or `lualatex` since otherwise `revtex` class conflicts with those new engines.

Answer (score 2):

Generally I share the opinion, that you should not include as many extensions as you can get. Use them sparely and only incase you really need them. I suggest this because:

- the more packages you use, the longer it probably needs to generate the document
- the less packages you use, the higher are chances to compile it on other systems, which might not have installed those special packages you might not actually using.
- the more packages you use, the more difficult it becomes to read the preamble
- the more packages you use, the chance of package-conflicts may increase. In a certain package renews commands, other packages rely on but having workarounds, those workarounds might fail.

However, I share your opinion, that it *sometimes* is (nonetheless) useful to include packages you *will* use in *every* file, like inputenc with UTF-8. Have a look here for some candidates: [What packages do people load by default in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/553/what-packages-do-people-load-by-default-in-latex)